# Extract text starts with specific words on R

Tags: r, text

I am extracting text from a string. The sample data looks like:

```
index <- c(1,2)
tag <- c('{"tags":["test_apple","test_orange","result_grape"]}',
'{"tags":["test_kiwi","test_pear","result_apple"]}')
sample <- data.frame(index,tag)
```

I want to create a new column and only extract the text stars with "result" from "tag". The result should look like

```
result <- c('"result_grape"','"result_apple"')
sampleresult <- data.frame(index,result)
```

I tried the tstrsplit, but it did not work.

```
tstrsplit(sampledata, "rep_")[[2]]
```

Comment: What didn't work? Did it give you an error/unexpected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise `stringr` library:

```
library(stringr)
result <- str_extract(sample[,2],"result_[A-z]+")
sampleresult <- data.frame(index,result)

  index       result
1     1 result_grape
2     2 result_apple
```

If you want to keep the quotes use `str_extract(sample[,2],"\"result_[A-z]+\"")`.